# How many objects will be created?

Tags: c++, oop

Here's my question - How many objects will be created after executing this code?

```
        class vehicle
        { public:
            int Weight, HorsePower;
            vehicle(int x, int y)
            { Weight = x;
              HorsePower = y;
            }
        };
        class car : public vehicle
        { public:
            car(int x, int y) : vehicle(x, y)
            { }
        };
        class motorcycle : private vehicle
        { public:
            motorcycle(int x, int y): 
            { Weight = x;
              HorsePower = y;
            }
        };

        int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
        { car Ferrari(4056,540);
          motorcycle Suzuki(429,103);
          return 0;
        }
```

What me and my friend argue about is that my point is 4 objects - car, motorcycle and 2 vehicles, because each derives vehicle.
Is this true?

Comment: If you ever intend to work with others in a professional context you should probably abandon the `{ public:` syntax...

Comment: What difference does it make?  That is, what application do you have that will behave differently depending on the answer to this question?

Answer (score 7):

The code is ill-formed:  `vehicle` has no default constructor and the sole constructor of `motorcycle` requires a default constructor for its `vehicle` base class.

Assuming a default constructor was added to `vehicle` (and the extraneous `:` is removed from the constructor of `motorcycle`), I count sixteen in the user code presented here:

- The two arguments to `main`:  `argc` and `argv`
- Eight in the construction of `Ferrari`:   `car`, `vehicle`, `Weight`, and `HorsePower` plus the `x` and `y` arguments of the `car` constructor and the `x` and `y` arguments of the `vehicle` constructor.
- Six in the construction of `Suzuki`:  `motorcycle`, `vehicle`, `Weight`, and `HorsePower` plus the `x` and `y` arguments to the `motorcycle` constructor.

I hope I haven't missed any.  Counting the number of *objects* that are created in a C++ program is a silly thing to do:  many, many objects get created, and usually it just doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes!  Also, some of these are "complete objects" and others are "member subobjects" or "base class subobjects", which are useful phrases for being precise about these things.

Comment: I did not think it was considered correct to call an `int x` field an "object" in C++.  Shows what I know about it...

Comment: @wberry: Being precise they are objects, in general they are not considered as such, and as James says it does not matter. Whether you call them objects or not, and whether you count the base subobject as an object or not (do you consider subobjects objects? or only complete objects?) won't modify the semantics of your program

Comment: I think I see.  So the compiler will essentially nest the parent class (struct) within the subclass struct for instances in memory, rather than using a "flattened" struct for subclasses?  Is that what is meant by the term "sub-object"?

Comment: Yes, the base class is "nested" within the derived class:  the base class is M bytes in size and the derived class is N bytes in size, where N >= M and the N bytes in the derived class includes the M bytes required to hold the base class.  [There is an exception for base classes that contain no members--those may be optimized away.]  I would consider this organization of memory to be "flattened" too, though, so I'm not really sure how to answer.

Comment: In short:  if you can take the address of something and that something isn't a function, it must be an object.  An object in C++ is simply _a region of storage_ with certain properties (the key property being that there is some way to obtain the address of the region of storage).  This is why `argc` in `main` is an object:  you can take its address, so it must occupy some region of storage.

Comment: OK, and that way multiple inheritance is handled by simply appending the fields from the parent classes/structs together in derivation order and aligning the result.  Makes sense.  +1

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that "in derivation order" is not required.  The compiler is free to arrange base class subobjects however it wants.

Comment: @aschepler:  Yes.  Breaking it down:  ten of these are _complete objects_, two are _base class subobjects_, and four are _data member subobjects_.  All of the function arguments, the `Ferrari` and the `Suzuki` are all _complete objects_.  There are two `vehicle` _base class subobjects_, and there are four _data member subobjects_:  two for each base class subobject.

Comment: @James - what about `std::cout` and many other objects from std library and any other objects linked to this program?

Comment: @PiotrNycz:  The answer expressly states that it only considers objects created _"in the user code presented here."_

Comment: @James I am not sure if "How many objects will be created after executing this code?" means "presented here". But anyway - do you by chance know the number of objects created in the "background"? I know this is compiler/compiler options dependent, but how to know this number? Maybe this should a SO regular question? However I don't really need this number - just curiosity...

Answer (score 2):

Only two *instances* (objects) will get created. `Ferrari` is a single object, even if its class (`car`) extends from `vehicle`. Same thing for `Suzuki`.

Comment: `car` has a base class sub-_object_ of type `vehicle`, though:  that `vehicle` sub-_object_ is an _object_.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for two.

Since a `car` and `motorcycle` cannot be separate entities from their base class. You will not have 4 separate instances. You also cannot call 4 destructors independently. The low-level implementation of such straight forward derivation also indicates 2. The Derived class would have same fields as the Base + plus its extra. You cannot instantiate a `car` without its `vehicle` part. Therefor, at least in my opinion, you cannot call it a separate object.

I also think the question in its form is very vague. What does it mean how many objects? I think properly it should be stated how many instances will be created. Or how many different object types.

There will be two instances in total. One being a `car`, one a `motorcycle` and both being `vehicle` at the same time.

PS. Another cross check that popped into my mind. Call `sizeof(Ferrari)`, `motorcycle(Suzuki)`. Sum it up. Then add 2x`vehicle` and get size of them too. The sum for 4 instances should be different, larger. I think that is enough to say, that there is less than "4 objects - car, motorcycle and 2 vehicles"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is '2'.  Although both objects inherit a base class, the base class is 'absorbed' into it.  Each object effectively acts as a single instance of the base class, with the 'new stuff' layered on top.

Think of it this way: Imagine taking a golf ball, then wrapping it with yarn/etc until it's the same size/weight/etc as a baseball. It looks different from a golf ball, and if you took it apart you'd be able to access the golf ball 'inside', but it would still be a single object.  In effect, the baseball *is a* golf ball that *has an* outer shell. But altogether, it is still a single object, even if 'golf balls' can be exist on their own, or be wrapped with other stuff to make new types of objects (like a bowling ball).